# TO_TIMESTAMP function can not be resolved in calcite

Tags: apache-calcite

I am using calcite library to query my data using API , I found function called TO_TIMESTAMP https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html but when I called it give exception that there are no function with this signature

what I try to do :

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(cast(ORGINALTIMESTAMP as varchar),cast('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' as varchar)) as  TEST from my_table
```

the exception that I got :

**No match found for function signature TO_TIMESTAMP(<CHARACTER>, <CHARACTER>)**

any idea what is the wrong that I am doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, include `fun=postgresql` in the JDBC connect string that you use to connect to Calcite, which starts with `jdbc:calcite:`.

In Calcite, `TO_TIMESTAMP` is a dialect-specific operator. This means that it is not included in the default dialect, and that is why it appears in [Calcite's table of dialect-specific operators](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#dialect-specific-operators).

The 'c' (compatibility) column for `TO_TIMESTAMP` contains the values 'o p', meaning that `TO_TIMESTAMP` is enabled in Oracle and PostgreSQL function tables. That is why `fun=postgresql` solves the problem; `fun=oracle` would also work.