# How to enable calcite's dialect-specific operator like TO_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, database, apache-calcite

I want to parser the sql query using calcite to do some SQL equivalence verification. But I found the default setting of calcite don't support dialect-specific operator such as `TO_TIMESTAMP`. The error is below:

```
No match found for function signature TO_TIMESTAMP(<CHARACTER>, <CHARACTER>)
```

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458533/to-timestamp-function-can-not-be-resolved-in-calcite) here said I can use jdbc to change the setting of calcite. But I cannot found where to use jdbc string to change the setting. Should I use some API in calcite to put the jdbc statement into calcite?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not invoking Calcite via JDBC, how are you calling it? Other APIs to Calcite have an equivalent of the JDBC `fun` parameter in the [answer you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458533/to-timestamp-function-can-not-be-resolved-in-calcite), but it's difficult to answer your question without more specifics.